# Entity framework Code First simple wpf/winforms repository layered example

Tags: entity-framework, repository, ef-code-first, code-first

Looking for the simple layered example that uses code first and repository, with either winforms or WPF (no ASP.NET).

I did not realize it is such an unusual question. Does anybody know of any example? I would like to use entity framework code first in layered project, but all samples I could find use ASP.NET (not familiar with), or use .edmx file, or are a simple console project. I can not connect the dots on how to actually make it work, and simple example would really help.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by this one, [EF Code First and WPF with the Chinook database](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145976/EF-Code-First-and-WPF-with-the-Chinook-database-Pa)

Follow it up by this [ONE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155210/EF-Code-First-and-WPF-with-the-Chinook-database-Pa.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but this example is neither layered nor uses the repository.

Comment: What do you mean by layered BTW ?? ... I tried finding the one with repository but couldn't find any. You can take a leap from this and learn repository separately

Comment: Example where database, business and UI are in separate layers. UI layer is either winforms or WPF. I did learn first about entity framework, then code first, then realized I need to learn repository. But I'm jet to find a (very) simple example using all (since I was not familiar with any of those).

Comment: Ohh k....I thought else....Anyways repository isn't the most difficult thing to understand. **Repositories are object representations of the underlying database (or file store or whatever you have chosen). Rather than work directly with the database, the domain model calls the methods defined by the repository, which in turn makes calls to the database to store and retrieve the model data. This allows us to isolate the model from the implementation of the persistence.**

Comment: Thank you, my question was about actual example, since I have made a simple project applying everything I've learned but something is missing and I'm not sure what.

Comment: You won't find an example of EF, repository and WPF..... You will have to either give up WPF in aid of Asp.net or Repository. I tried finding one....Sorry

Comment: Thank you for your time, my problem is I'm not familiar with ASP.NET and how to modify those examples. There are also a lot of examples using repository with .edmx file, but I have not enough knowledge to modify them to use Code First.